# How does substitution values work in assert_select of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently working on a project which uses rails 4.2.10. And I want to use `assert_select` in a test.

The code I want to use is this:

```
node.id = 6
assert_select "div:match('class', ?)", "note-nid-#{node.id}", false
```

I wanted to confirm that am I selecting a div with class which has name note-nid-6. 
An element something like this:

```
<div class="note-nid-6">
```

or it means something else?

I am also trying to  make the false equality to true in the code and then it gave this error:

```
 Minitest::Assertion: Expected at least 1 element matching "div:match('class', "note-nid-6")", found 0..
```

So, according to this, it means that I am asserting if div:match('class', "note-nid-6") is there or not. I wanted to find that there should be no presence of `<div class="note-nid-6">`. If there is any other way, then please suggest that.

Comment: Try This `assert_select "div.?", /note-nid-\d+/`

Comment: How to include the node.id variable in the regex?

Comment: `assert_select "div.?", /note-nid-#{node.id}/`

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '"(?-mix:note-nid-6)"' after '.' (called from block in <class:NotesControllerTest> at /home/sourav/Documents/gsoc/plots2/test/functional/notes_controller_test.rb:239)

Comment: It gave this warning